# Error when installing .Net 4.0 on Win 2008 R2 ('Blocking Issues')

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install .Net 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 but the setup interrups with a message "Blocking Issues". There is a link to Readme file that says:

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 (not supported on Server Core Role).
```

How to solve?

Comment: Be sure to read the [Overview section](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833) for the restrictions and requirements to get .NET on server core.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 R2 was released before .Net 4.0 and hence 4.0 is not supported. With SP1 however, the problem is solve.

Download and install SP1 for Windows Server 2008 R2.

Ref: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22833

P.S.: make sure you the right version of .net installer (Server Core / Full) according to your windows.